# Stack overflow on list traversal

Tags: c#

I've sourced my data for a treeview using the Proces datastructure below. expanded simply indicates whether or not the tree item has been expanded to show all of its children. This is my attempt to iterate through a map all showing items into a DataTable.

```
public class Proces
{
    public string PN { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public string PartType { get; set; }
    public decimal PricePer { get; set; }
    public string Mfr { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public int OnOrder { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public bool expanded { get; set; } = false;

    public List<Proces> subProcesses { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to map this out into a DataTable, but i keep getting a stack overflow.

```
        void generateShownTree(List<Proces> proccess)
        {
            foreach (Proces proc in processes)
            {
                DataRow drNew = export.NewRow();
                drNew["Parent"] = proc.parent;
                drNew["PN"] = proc.PN;
                drNew["Description"] = proc.Description;
                drNew["Qty"] = proc.Qty;
                drNew["PartType"] = proc.PartType;
                drNew["PricePer"] = proc.PricePer;
                drNew["Mfr"] = proc.Mfr;
                drNew["Stock"] = proc.Stock;
                drNew["OnOrder"] = proc.OnOrder;
                export.Rows.Add(drNew);

                if (proc.expanded == true)
                {
                    foreach (Proces subProc in proc.subProcesses)
                    {
                        subProc.parent = proc.PN;
                        drNew = export.NewRow();
                        drNew["Parent"] = subProc.parent;
                        drNew["PN"] = subProc.PN;
                        drNew["Description"] = subProc.Description;
                        drNew["Qty"] = subProc.Qty;
                        drNew["PartType"] = subProc.PartType;
                        drNew["PricePer"] = subProc.PricePer;
                        drNew["Mfr"] = subProc.Mfr;
                        drNew["Stock"] = subProc.Stock;
                        drNew["OnOrder"] = subProc.OnOrder;
                        export.Rows.Add(drNew);

                        generateShownTree(proc.subProcesses);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That a typo? You're iterating over "processes" when your method argument is called "proccess".

Comment: It's much easier to spot the error if you remove unnessesary code (the drNew=-lines) and tell if i.e. `proc.expanded` is true.I guess you made a mistake at the recursive call : `generateShownTree(proc.subProcesses);` -> `generateShownTree(subProc.subProcesses);`

Comment: You're not traversing a list, you're traversing a *tree*.  Big difference.

Comment: Look for two processes who have each other the parent.

Comment: @Chriz Isn't it cleaner to do it this way rather than writing it all out as a string passed to rows.Add?

Comment: @Tristan Sry if i didnt make it clear. I meant to show only the lines nessesary to reproduce the problem here on stackoverflow. The lines drNew =...;drNew=...;drNew=...; add nothing but height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't want to iterate the list of subprocesses as well as invoke the `generateShownTree` method recursively. I also changed the name of the argument passed to `generateShownTree` to match the object being iterated.

```
static void generateShownTree(List<Proces> processes)
{
    foreach (Proces proc in processes)
    {
        DataRow drNew = export.NewRow();
        drNew["Parent"] = proc.parent;
        drNew["PN"] = proc.PN;
        drNew["Description"] = proc.Description;
        drNew["Qty"] = proc.Qty;
        drNew["PartType"] = proc.PartType;
        drNew["PricePer"] = proc.PricePer;
        drNew["Mfr"] = proc.Mfr;
        drNew["Stock"] = proc.Stock;
        drNew["OnOrder"] = proc.OnOrder;
        export.Rows.Add(drNew);

        if (proc.expanded)
        {
            generateShownTree(proc.subProcesses);
        }
    }
}
```